# Struggling to understanding Hahn-Jordan dicomposition theorem and concepts clarification

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

From https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Jordan_decomposition_(of_a_signed_measure)#Ha ：

> Consider a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of a set $X$ and
> a signed measure $\mu$ on it, i.e. a $\sigma$ -additive function $\mu:
> > \mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The **Jordan decomposition**
> states the existence of two nonnegative measures $\mu^{+}$ and
> $\mu^{-}$ which are mutually singular and such that
> $\mu=\mu^{+}-\mu^{-}$. The property of being mutually singular
> translates into the existence of a set $X^{+} \in \mathcal{B}$ such
> that $\mu^{+}\left(X \backslash X^{+}\right)=0$ and
> $\mu^{-}\left(X^{+}\right)=0$ (see Section 29 of $[\mathrm{Ha}]$ ). If
> we denote by $X^{-}$ the complement of $X^{+},$ we then conclude that
> $\mu(A) \geq 0$ for any $A \in \mathcal{B}$ with $A \subset X^{+}$ and
> $\mu(A) \leq 0$ for any $A \in \mathcal{B}$ with $A \subset X^{-}$.
> **The Hahn decomposition** is the decomposition of $X$ into the subsets $X^{+}$ and $X^{-}$. Observe however that, while the two
> measures $\mu^{+}$ and $\mu^{-}$ are uniquely determined by the
> property given above, the sets $X^{+}$ and $X^{-}$ are not.

I am very confused because we were introduced to integration before the concept of sign-measure. And we are given $\int X d\mu=\int X^+ d\mu -\int X^- d\mu$ as the definition of integration when $X$ is a general measurable function or is a.e measurable function **if $\int X$ exists**. It seems very naturally $\mu^+=\int X^+d\mu$ and $\mu^-=\int X^- d\mu$ because $\int X^+d\mu=\int X1_{[X\geq0]}+\int0\times1_{[X<0]}$ and $\int X^-d\mu=\int -X1_{[X\leq0]}+\int0\times1_{[X>0]}$. **Is Hahn-Jordan decomposition justying what we have done before?** What does it mean that $X^+$ and $X^-$ are not uniquely determined yet $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$ are?

Besides, in the encyclopedia, it says that

> The property of being mutually singular
> translates into the existence of a set $X^{+} \in \mathcal{B}$ such
> that $\mu^{+}\left(X \backslash X^{+}\right)=0$ and
> $\mu^{-}\left(X^{+}\right)=0$

I find this definition of singular disconnected from what's been provided on the textbook:

> We say $\phi$ is singular with respect to $\mu,$ denoted by $\phi \perp \mu,$ if there exists a set $N \in \mathcal{A}$ for which $\mu(N)=0$ while $|\phi|\left(N^{c}\right)=0$

which to my own understanding means: $\phi\perp\mu \Leftrightarrow \exists N\in\mathcal{A},\mu(N)=0\text{ and }|\phi|(N^c)=0$, and mutually singular means $\mu_1\perp\mu_2$ and $\mu_2\perp\mu_1$. How can I connect this two definition and show they are essentially the same?

Comment: You used the same letter $X$ for measurable sets and later for *functions* under integration. The definition of integral you mention is for *nonnegative* measures, and, given the Jordan decomposition of a signed measure, we will simply *define* $\int f\,d\mu:=\int f\,d\mu^+\,-\,\int f\,d\mu^-$ using integrals with respect to nonnegative measures.

Comment: @Berci Hi, Thank you so much for your comment! I am confused. In Halmous Measure Theory section 29, I found If $(X, S, \mu)$ is a measure space and $f$ is an integrable function on $X,$ then the set function $\nu,$ defined by $\nu(E)=\int_{E} f(x) d \mu(x),$ is a finite signed measure, and
$
\boldsymbol{\nu}^{+}(E)=\int_{E} f^{+} d \mu, \quad \boldsymbol{\nu}^{-}(E)=\int_{\boldsymbol{B}} f^{-} d \mu
$. If $\mu$ is a measure on measure space $(X,\mathcal{S})$, won't $\mu$ be non-negative? Then what is $\mu^-$?

Comment: A *signed measure* might take negative values, and indeed $E\mapsto \int_E f\,d\mu$ is a good example of signed measures. For this specific signed measure $\nu$ its Jordan decomposition is indeed given by the positive and negative parts of $f$.

Comment: @Berci Thank you so much I think I understand what you meant